# disable failSafeCheck Python PyAutoGui without editing the pyautogui file

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

So I'm using PyCharm as a python editor, and I don't know if it's because of my editor, but whenever I run a simple PyAutoGui program such as:

```
import time, pyautogui

time.sleep(3)

while True:
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'r')
    time.sleep(15)
```

for too long, I keep getting an error *(I don't have that error currently, because I usually have to wait a long time before getting the error from pyautogui. But it looks something like) :*

```
PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to a corner of the screen.
```

I'm not very experienced with Python PyAutoGui module, but is there a way to disable that safe-check without doing something in the pyautogui python file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck! Just add `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True` right after importing the library.

Check out their [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#fail-safes) it has a lot of good info.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But after I got the error, it said that turning it off isn't recommended. Perhaps is there another way?

Comment: I have the same issue where if I run my program for a few hours, pyautogui's failsafe triggers even though my mouse never moves to the top left corner of the screen. Sadly, the only fix I'm aware of is to disable it and I wouldn't worry too much about it saying it's not recommended. You only really need the failsafe while testing and building the code incase your mouse starts moving too much and you can no longer click to stop the program. Once it's ready and you want it to run for a few hours, disable the failsafe.

Comment: You can also try other libraries like [mouse](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/) and [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) which function the same as pyautogui but don't have failsafes built in.

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of PyAutoGUI. The warning is just a warning; you can turn off the fail-safe feature. It's just that often when writing scripts that control the mouse, if it gets out of control, you might not be able to use the mouse to close the application. I've been in situations where the only thing I can do is forcibly turn off the computer. So, just keep that in mind.